# netcat between mac and linux only working in one direction

Tags: linux, macos, networking, mac, netcat

I have two machines on the same local network. One is a Mac (192.168.42.74) and one is a Dell (192.168.42.75) running Kubuntu Linux.

If I issue 'nc -l 12345' on the Mac and issue 'echo "blah" | nc 192.168.42.74 12345' from the Linux Machine, I see "blah" show up on the other end at the Mac...

But if I reverse the roles and issue 'nc -l 12345' from the Linux Machine and 'echo "blah" | nc 192.168.42.75 12345' from the Mac, I don't get anything showing up on the other side.

Does anyone know why there is this asymmetry between the machines? Not sure where to start troubleshooting this one.

Comment: Check your firewall on the Kubuntu machine.

Comment: Works perfectly between my Kubuntu and my Mac OS, listen to @heavyd!